# Meaning of "Provided the teacher draws attention to this"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Most of all though, it is through the language which occurs in the classroom that students can really see how the relationships between words matter, **provided the teacher draws attention to this**.

Here, what does it mean **provided the teacher draws attention to this** (With grammar).

Comment: You can google **provided** or consult any on-line dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

> **provided** the teacher draws attention to this

is same as saying:

> **if** the teacher draws attention to this

or

> **assuming** the teacher draws attention to this

or even better:

> **with the condition that** the teacher draws attention to this